# Can an electric field "cancel" gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

As I understand it the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) in the presence of an [electromagnetic field tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) and non-interacting matter $M$ is given by:
$$S=\int\Big[\frac{1}{2\kappa}{\cal R}-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+{\cal L}_M\Big]\sqrt{-g}\ d^4x.\tag{1}$$
It seems that we can apply an electromagnetic field tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ given by
$$\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}={\cal L}_M\tag{2}$$ so that we cancel the gravity of the matter inside some region to end up with the vacuum Einstein-Hilbert action
$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa}\int{\cal R}\sqrt{-g}\ d^4x.\tag{3}$$
Now we have
$$F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=2(B^2-\frac{E^2}{c^2}).\tag{4}$$
If we assume that we have pressureless matter at rest then
$${\cal L}_M=-\rho_Mc^2.\tag{5}$$
By substituting Eqns.(4-5) into Eqn.(2), taking the magnetic field strength $B=0$, and using $\epsilon_0 \mu_0 = 1/c^2$, we find:
$$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2=\rho_Mc^2.\tag{6}$$
Thus it seems that the energy density of the electric field cancels the gravitational effect of the energy density of matter. If $\rho_M=10^3$ kg/m$^3$ then the electric field strength needed to cancel the gravity is $10^{15}$ V/m. This is very large but less than the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) of $10^{18}$ V/m at which the electromagnetic field becomes nonlinear.

Does this make sense?

**Correction**

The $T_{00}$ component of the [electromagnetic stress energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is strictly positive. I was wrong.

Comment: Do you know the difference between off- and on-shell equations, and how this difference constrains how you can substitute in an action?

Comment: What do you mean by cancelling gravity here? Even if (2) is true, it doesn't mean that the stress-energy tensor is zero (at least globally). Thus even if $R_{ab}=0$ (locally in some region), the Weyl tensor will be non-zero.

Comment: I think you probably know your construction can't be right. The energy density $\rho_M$ for pressureless matter is strictly positive. The energy density for an electric field $\sim +E^2$ is strictly positive. So the total energy density is positive. Since one of Einstein's equations relates the $00$ component of the Einstein tensor to the energy density, there is no cancellation that can occur on the right hand side, which is a sum of positive terms.

Comment: Andrew you’re right the $T_{00}$ component of the electromagnetic stress energy tensor is strictly positive. I was wrong.

Comment: I guess the Einstein equations with the Electromagnetic stress-energy tensor are on-shell and therefore apply to electromagnetic waves that obey $|E|=|B|c$. The Einstein-Hilbert action with the electromagnetic tensor term applies to both off and on-shell.